# LiDAR online training

Tags: lidar, references, training

Beside ESRI's LIDAR online training, I'd like to work on some hands-on training that I can learn about LIDAR. Are there any good LiDAR out there that I can get some training with the datasets?

Comment: https://coast.noaa.gov/digitalcoast/training/intro-lidar.html

Comment: Natural Resources Wales provide free LiDAR: http://lle.gov.wales/catalogue/item/lidarcompositedataset/?lang=en

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The NSF OpenTopography Facility has some excellent resources (software descriptions and tutorials including videos) and an abundance of freely available LiDAR data (both LAS point clouds and interpolated grids) to use. Here is a link: http://www.opentopography.org/   Downloading the data requires registration but it is well worth the effort.

Answer (score 2):

Not specifically an online training but I took the Leveraging Imagery and Raster Data in ArcGIS full day technical seminar offered at this year ESRI Conferences which was pretty good. Among other things is focuses on:

- Efficient management of imagery and LiDAR using 
  mosaic dataset
- Tips, tricks and best practices for managing imagery & 
  LiDAR on an enterprise level

Answer (score 2):

The USFS application FUSION, although specific to forest resources, offers a good training. FUSION is nice because it has a very user-intuitive interface, but also a command line interface for more heavy lifting.

The training is available at the [Remote Sensing Applications Center](http://www.fs.fed.us/eng/rsac/lidar_training/)
.